# Converting Text File From String to List

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I need help converting this text file (https://www.gutenberg.org/files/768/768.txt) from a string to a list on Google Colab. I need the text file to start after “ccx074@pglaf.org”, and end before “END OF THE PROJECT GUTENBERG EBOOK WUTHERING HEIGHTS in order to have an accurate total of the word count. Listed below is the coding that I have so far.

```
# download and installing pyspark in colab
!pip install -q pyspark

# download Wuthering Heights, by Emily Bronte
!wget -q https://www.gutenberg.org/files/768/768.txt

from pyspark import SparkContext
 sc = SparkContext()

import os.path
baseDir = os.path.join('data')
inputPath = os.path.join('/content/768.txt')
fileName = os.path.join(baseDir, inputPath)
with open('/content/768.txt','r') as f:
text = f.read()

#GET START LOC
start_loc = text.find("ccx074@pglaf.org") + len("ccx074@pglaf.org")

#GET END LOC
end_loc = text[start_loc:].find("***")

#SLICE THE TEXT STRING AND INDEXES
text[start_loc:start_loc+end_loc].replace("\n", " ")
```

Comment: What is the output of your current code?

Comment: you might wanna save the last line in another variable to check the result in a print. replace is not gonna modify the content of `text`

Comment: It shows all of the text file for Wuthering Heights, but it is in the form of a string.

Comment: "accurate total of the word count" - you mean `len(result.split())`?

Comment: @NicoleBeasley Can you show us the code where you print the results? As I stated earlier, I'm guessing you're printing the variable `text`, which would be in issue because the method `replace()` is not affecting its value. Strings are immutable in Python so you cannot change their values. That line at the end returns the new value you are looking for, so you need to assign it to another variable (let's say `new_text`) and then print it. Also @bertdida mentioned `split` and I think you need to use it to split the text into values of a list